# Trying to use Apache TelnetClient to establish a TLS telnet session via a Port forwarding Proxy

Tags: ssl, proxy, client, telnet

I'm trying to write a Java program that will establish a Telnet session to a TLS enabled server that is only accessible via a Port Forwarding Proxy.

In the past I have successfully used TelnetClient to establish telnet sessions with non-TLS servers, and TLS Servers, but I've never had to use a proxy.

I've been struggling with this for a while now, so it's time to ask the experts.

Here's a simple code example that illustrates the problem I'm getting. After I address the reader, I don't get anything returned, and the reader then blocks:

'''public class SimpleTest {

```
public static PrintStream  psout;


static void write(String value) {
    try {
        psout.println(value);
        psout.flush();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     TelnetClient telnet;
     TelnetReader tr;

     String host="192.168.82.72";   
     int    port=992;
     
     try {
            // 1. Create the TelnetClient Object 
            telnet = new TelnetClient();
            
            // 2. Set up our own SocketFactory (For SSL)
            SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            telnet.setSocketFactory(sslsocketfactory);
            
            // 3. Set the proxy
            System.setProperty("socksProxyHost","127.0.0.1");
            System.setProperty("socksProxyPort","6600");
            
            Proxy socksProxy  = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 6600));
            telnet.setProxy(socksProxy);
            
            
            // 4. Connect
            telnet.connect(host, port);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            
            // 5. Start the reader
            tr = new TelnetReader(telnet.getInputStream());
            Thread reader = new Thread (tr);
            reader.start();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            
            // 6. Address the output stream
            String r;
            psout = new PrintStream(telnet.getOutputStream());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            r = tr.get();          // <- r is null!!
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

}
'''

What am I doing wrong?

TIA John

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved the problem. I found that the setProxy method (in the Apache code) reset the SocketFactory.  I downloaded the Apache code and commented out that line. When I did that my code works just fine.